# Like on Website not showing up in News Feed

Tags: facebook-like, feed

I've been googling and trying to find some answers to this, but haven't been successful.  This used to work just fine.

I am using wordpress and a WP FB Like Plugin to create the like button on my site and link it back to the FB app I created using the open graph system so that when you hit "like" on a page on my website it *should* show up in the newsfeed.  Now, it only shows up in the newsfeed if I write a comment.  If I just hit like and no comment, it only shows up on my wall.  Is this something new with FB?  I have tested on my own personal FB page and created a new test FB page (that isn't an admin on my business page) to see if there was a difference (nope, same problem).

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On my FB, when I hit the like button on a website (my phpBB forum for example), it never shows up in the news feed, but it shows up on my wall (hit "Profile"). It shows up on everyone else's newsfeed, then I think it will show up on yours if people leave comments.

As I recall, it used to work a little differently, so I don't think you're crazy, but this is how it works for me now.

You may have better luck asking your question here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to add that I had a friend test this out for me and when he liked a page on my website it did in fact show up on my news feed. It would be nice, for testing purposes, to be able to see that this happens on your own fb page (that I can see the like in my newsfeed) instead of having to have someone else test it out.

Thanks for your help!